# Raspberry Pi Zero: act as USB mass storage using power port, use data USB port for Wi-Fi

Tags: usb, pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero (1.3) running Debian Jessie (full); the image name is `2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img`. I've ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and updated the packages on it.

I have it connected to my laptop (Mac) with an OTG data cable, connected to the power port on the Raspberry Pi Zero. I connected a Wi-Fi adapter to the  Raspberry Pi Zero data USB port, which I use to SSH into it (the Wi-Fi works fine).

I'm trying to make it act as a mass storage device, with `g_mass_storage`, following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a). However, trying to do so, my Raspberry Pi Zero "hangs"—

```
$ sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.0.6 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I have two questions.

1. Is what I want feasible? Ie, can I use the power port to transfer data from a connected machine to the Raspberry Pi Zero in mass storage mode, while still using it to connect to the Wi-Fi by having a Wi-Fi adapter connected to the data port?
2. Why does it hang, is this expected (ie, the data port must be used for USB mass storage, and cannot operate as a Wi-Fi adapter once the `g_mass_storage` module is loaded)?

Answer (score 4):

> can I use the power port to transfer data

Your plan on using the power port as data already failed. No, the power port is **power only**.

---

Here's another plan:

```
                     /-> Wifi Adapter
Pi Zero <-> USB hub <
                     \-> male-to-male USB cable plugged to the PC
```

OTG does not allow being a master and a slave at the same time, so a hub would not work.

---

Your best bet would be to do everything involving data over WiFi (FTP, Samba, etc.) An alternative would be via Ethernet. This will effectively turn your Pi Zero into a Wired/Wireless NAS.

Comment: Thank you @PandaLion. Theoretically, could it switch modes from host to slave at will? Ie, receive data while in slave mode, once transfer is complete, switch over to master mode to use the Wi-Fi?

Comment: @PiZeroUser That'll cause *serious* issues with the other plugged-in devices.